# React で prop 受け渡しの shorthand はありますか？

Tags: javascript, reactjs

例えば Component の extra という props を固定したコンポーネントを作るときに

```js
const HogeComponent = props => <Component {...props} extra='hoge' />
```

と書けますが、以下のように省略して書く方法はありますか？

```js
const HogeComponent = Component.bind({ extra: 'hoge' })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[High-Order Component](https://ja.reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)(通称HoC)を利用する方法があります。書き方は独特ではありますが、デザインパターンの[Factory Methodパターン](https://www.techscore.com/tech/DesignPattern/FactoryMethod.html/)とやっていることは変わりません。コンポーネントを作る関数を定義してあげればよいのです。

例えば、コメントを投稿するユーザー名を固定するコンポーネントを使いまわしたいとき、次のようのにかけます。

```
import React from "react";

const Comment = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p className="name">
        <strong>{props.name}</strong>
      </p>
      <p className="message">{props.message}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const createComponent = init => props => <Comment {...{ ...init, ...props }} />;

export default function App() {
  const HogeComponent = createComponent({ name: "hoge" }); // hogeで固定
  const FugaComponent = createComponent({ name: "fuga" }); // fugaで固定
  return (
    <>
      <HogeComponent message="hoge" />
      <FugaComponent message="fuga" />
      <HogeComponent message="hoge hoge" />
      <FugaComponent message="fuga fuga" />
    </>
  );
}
```

1つ効果的に利用な用途としては、初期化が高コストだが、それをよく使い回す場合です。例えばブログの記事をSingle Page Applicationとして作成し、ページ遷移が発生するたびに、ページ全体を再生成するのは非効率です。そのため、記事の本文以外は初期化しておき、ページの遷移を行うときは記事の内容のみを変更するようにすれば、処理コスト的に効率的であることがわかるでしょう。